# iPhone Tableview - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I have a view with a `button` and a `label` on it. Now when I click on that button, I will be taken to another page (view) that displays a `Tableview` with some values populated in it.

I have successfully coded the `button` and the `label` view, and also the populating part of the `tableview`.

Now what I need to do is, when I click on an item or a row, in the `tableview`, that value should be shown on the previous page (that contained a `button` and a `label`). How should I do this? Any idea?

Note: I can't provide any code, because I am on my Linux machine :(

Comment: You can use a delegate protocol for that. I can show you an example if you need.

Comment: Yes Please, it would be great

Comment: you just got it from ender...that should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the best solution is coding a protocol.

In `myProtocol.h`

```
@protocol myProtocol

-(void) didSelectItem: (id) yourItem;

@end
```

Then, in the interface file of the viewController that contains your tableView:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    id <myProtocol> selectionDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign)  id <myProtocol> selectionDelegate;
```

In .m file:

```
 @synthesize selectionDelegate;



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //do something with your data and pass it to the delegate.
    [self.selectionDelegate didSelectItem:myObject];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

The viewController that contains the button and the label must implement your delegate:

In .h:

```
@interface OtherViewController : UIViewController <myProtocol>  {


...

}
```

In .m:

```
-(void) didSelectItem: (id) yourItem
{
    //do something with your item, set the label and everything...

}
```

**In some part of your code you will have to set the delegate**

Hope this helps

Comment: SO is `yourItem` contain the Item that i selected from the `TableView` ?

Comment: Yes, i guess you have your tableview items in a array. All you have to do is get the selected item from the array and pass it to the delegate. If you have to send multiple objects the best structure is a NSMutableDictionary. An array of NSMutableDictionary is a flexible and easy to use solution for tableviews

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to go back to your previous view, if you've been using a `UINavigationController` to push your table view controller then there should be a back button to get you back.  If you need to react to the tapping of a specific cell, override the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: I need to get the value of the `cell` that i clicked and displayed the `label` in the previous view (The view that has a `button` and a `label`)